# Feeding image into tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, mnist, softmax

I am new to using TensorFlow. So I wastrying the MNIST tutorials in ML for beginners. The code runs just fine. But what if I want to input an image of my own, which has say a handwritten number on it, and se if it predicts what number it might be? How do I feed my own image into the TensorFlow program?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py).

If you look at `x`, the shape is `[None, 784]`. To feed your own image in, you'll have to store the image as a variable (loading it using PIL or OpenCV or something), flatten it, wrap it in a list, and pass it to the graph in the `feed_dict`, looking something like this:

```
sess.run(y_, feed_dict={x: [np.flatten(image_you_loaded_in)]})
```

It will need to be a 28x28 image in order for this code to work without modification.